# How to set a max size of each item in a list passed to the rest api?

Tags: java, rest

I have this REST API built that accepts a fleetName and list of serialNumbers. I know that I can limit the character size of fleetName as shown, but is there any way to limit the character length on each item in the list of serial numbers in this rest call?

REST Call:

```java
@GetMapping("/rest/slt/fleet/save")
public Fleet saveFleet(@RequestParam(value = "fleetName") @Max(value = 40) String fleetName,
            @RequestParam(value = "serialNoList") String[] serialNoList) {

    return fleetService.saveFleet(fleetName, serialNoList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return RuntimeException for example:

```
@GetMapping("/rest/slt/fleet/save")
public Fleet saveFleet(@RequestParam(value = "fleetName") String fleetName,
    @RequestParam(value = "serialNoList") String[] serialNoList) {
    return fleetService.saveFleet(fleetName, serialNoList);
}
```

And then in your class FleetService you will create some validation.

```
    public void saveFleet(final String fleetName) {
    if (fleetName.length() > 40) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Maximum size is 40");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSR303 does not inspect Arrays.  Just validate it in your controller directly or if you are using Hibernate Validator see this answer.

[Hibernate ScriptAssert for arrays validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859352/hibernate-scriptassert-for-arrays-validation)

You can write a custom Javascript or any JSR223 implementation that will do your validation.

If you are on Spring Boot 2.3 make sure you get the new validator starter

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use @Length(max = 40) or @Size(max = 40), do not use @Max for String